# How to code for horizontal scrolling for BrowserField in BB

Tags: blackberry, horizontal-scrolling, browserfield

I am new to BB development. I want to load a WebView inside my BB application without using the default device browser to load the URL. Following is the code I have used inside my *BrowserScreen* class which extends **MainScreen**.

```
    BrowserField browserField = new BrowserField(myBrowserFieldConfig);
    browserField.addListener(myBrowserFieldListener);
    add(browserField);
    browserField.requestContent("http://www.myurl.com/");
```

This will load the URL and display the web page without any error. Only issue is that web site is not developed specifically mobile devices. So the width of the web site is beyond the BB device screen. I can only scroll vertically not horizontally. How can I programmatically enable horizontal scrolling in `BrowserField`.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: BrowserFieldConfig myBrowserFieldConfig = new BrowserFieldConfig();
                myBrowserFieldConfig.setProperty(BrowserFieldConfig.NAVIGATION_MODE,BrowserFieldConfig.NAVIGATION_MODE_POINTER);

Comment: I have already given that. That code is inside _MyBrowserFieldConfig_ class which extends `BrowserFieldConfig`. First line of my above code I have include that instance as _myBrowserFieldConfig_. I hope that is correct.

Comment: did you set this ? BrowserFieldConfig.NAVIGATION_MODE,BrowserField‌​Config.NAVIGATION_MODE_POINTER

Comment: Yes, I have added that code. Only difference is I have added all the configurations in separate class which extends the `BrowserFieldConfig`

Answer (score 1):

This code should work:

```
public class YourClass extends MainScreen {   
    public YourClass()   {
        //Apply config here if you want
        BrowserField myBrowserField=new BrowserField();
        HorizontalFieldManager manager=new HorizontalFieldManager(Manager.HORIZONTAL_SCROLL|Manager.VERTICAL_SCROLL);
        manager.add(myBrowserField);
        this.add(manager);   
    } 
}
```